# How can I multi-thread 3 different functions that return the same value and pick the fastest

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am using the threading module and have 3 different functions where they return the same value but use different methods to return that value.

I want and ID and will call it my_id

For example:

Function #1: Scrape website using a mobile endpoint and parsing the json for my_id

Function #2: Scrape website using desktop endpoint and parse json for my_id

Function #3: Scrape desktop website HTML and find my_id

What I would like to do is run each function at the same time and whichever one returns my_id the fastest, I take it and continue with my code.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `concurrent.futures.`

Create three threads and launch them using `concurrent.futures.Executor.submit()`
This returns you the future objects for each of the thread.

Then you can

```
concurrent.futures.wait(fs, timeout=None, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

which will block the main thread, until one of the 3 child threads complete.

Then you can go ahead and use your result.

> ```
> concurrent.futures.wait Returns a named 2-tuple of sets. The first set, named done and not_done
> ```

You can get your result from the completed futures object using the result() method, and you can safely shutdown the executor using the Executor.shutdown()

You can add your objects to a list, and start them like:

`futures = []
for task in task_list:
        futures.append(executor.submit(task.run))
concurrent.futures.wait(futures,timeout=None,return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)`

Comment: ok, I'm not familiar with concurrent, so is the 'fs' parameter the function that has started my threads?

for example, would I have 1 function that starts the 3 threads of the 3 functions and then concurrent would just run that or? I'm just newer to multithreading so some of this is hard for me to conceptualize. Thanks

Comment: You have 3 objects, which does 3 different things, but all of them can have a run() method in them, which will start actual job. You supply this method to the executor.submit()
You can add your objects to a list, and start them like:
`futures = []
for task in task_list:
        futures.append(executor.submit(task.run))`